# What is the best practice in REST-Api, to pass structured data or key-value pair?

Tags: json, rest, data-structures, api-design

I have a data-structure similar to the given below, which I am supposed to process. I am designing an API which should accept a POST request similar to the one given below. (ignore the headers, etc)


`{
    "Name" : "Johny English",
    "Id": "534dsf",
    "Message":[
        {
            "Header":"Country of origin",
            "Value":"England"
        },
        {
            "Header":"Nature of work",
            "Value":"Secret Agent/Spy"
        }
    ]
}`

Some how I do not feel, its a correct way to pass/accept data. Here I am talking about structured data vs. Key-Value pair. While I can extract the fields ("Name", "Id") directly to an object attributes, but for Key-Value pairs, I need to loop through the collection and compare with strings (eg. "Nature of Work") to extract values.

I searched few sites, looking for any best practices, could not reach into any conclusion. Is there any best practice, suggestions etc.

Comment: It's developer approach on how to structure JSON data. It is always better to structure data according to object and it's value. This approach will make easier to perform different operations while it will be easy to retrieve data. Only keep objects in Array when it's really necessary to keep.

Comment: I agree with @Bibek. It is always better to structure data according to object as it will be easy to deserialize posted values into the object. Otherwise you will have to write custom logic to deserialize the data from key value pair.

Comment: Strange, there's no concrete discussion on this topic. Because I feel both the approaches are equally accepted.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you are going to find any firm, evidence based arguments against including a list of key value pairs in your message schema.  But that's the sort of thing to look for - people writing about message schema design, and how to design messages to support change, and so on.

As a practical matter, there's not a whole lot of difference

```
{
    "Name" : "Johny English",
    "Id": "534dsf",
    "Message":[
        {
            "Header":"Country of origin",
            "Value":"England"
        },
        {
            "Header":"Nature of work",
            "Value":"Secret Agent/Spy"
        }
    ]
}
```

or

```
{
    "Name" : "Johny English",
    "Id": "534dsf",
    "Message": {
        "Country of origin": "England",
        "Nature of work": "Secret Agent/Spy"
    }
}
```

In the early days of the world wide web, "everything" is key value pairs, because it was easy to describe a collection of key value pairs in such a way that a general-purpose component, like a web browser, could work with it (ie, definitions of HTML forms).  It got the job done.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually good to structure your response data the same as what you'd expect the input of the corresponding POST, PUT, and PATCH endpoints to be. This allows record alteration to not require the consuming entity to transform the data first. So in that context, arrays of objects with "name"/"value" fields is much easier to write input validation for.